# A word starting with t but ends with other than e

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I am trying to create a regex that starts with t or T and doesn't end with e letter. I tried the code below so far, but it's not giving me the desirable result. Could anyone show me what is exactly missing here?

```
my_str = my_file.read()

word = re.findall("[tT].*[^e]$", my_str)

print(word)
```

Comment: Are you trying to find words within a full sentence/text? Or is it some database with a single word per line? In other words, do you have some sample data? Btw, currently you allow for any character other than newline in between (including space characters).

Comment: Yes, it is a text within the file.

Comment: You may want to know that `\b` in a regex matches a word boundary…

Comment: Next, you have to decid what is a legal character inside a word. Probably `[A-Za-z]` is a better guess than your `.` (that is, anything comprising punctuation and spaces).

Comment: Finally, if you have solved your problem you could post an answer that I'll be glad to upvote.

Comment: In this text "Here we denote time with the variable t, distance with x." does the word "t"  satisfy your criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
\bt(?:[a-z]*[a-df-z])?\b
\bt[a-z]*\b(?<!e)
```

Just for completeness, here is a regex to match any word starting with a Cyrillic `т` and not ending with a Cyrillic `е`:

```py
\bт[^\W\d_]*\b(?<!е)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/JBe7EI/1), [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/JBe7EI/2) and a [Cyrillic regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JBe7EI/3).

If you need a case insensitive matching, add `re.I`:

```py
re.findall(r'\bt(?:[a-z]*[a-df-z])?\b', text, re.I)
```

And a note on word boundaries: if the words can be glued to `_` or digits, use letter boundaries rather than word boundaries:

```py
r'(?<![a-z])t(?:[a-z]*[a-df-z])?(?![a-z])'
r'(?<![^\W\d_])т[^\W\d_]*(?![^\W\d_])(?<!е)' # Unicode letter boundaries
```

**Regex details**

- `\b` - word boundary (start of string or a position immediately after a char other than a digit, letter, underscore)
- `(?<![a-z])` (`(?<![^\W\d_])` is a Unicode aware equivalent) - a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is not immediately preceded with a letter
- `t` - a `t` letter
- `(?:[a-z]*[a-df-z])?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 0 or more letters and then a letter other than `e`
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?![a-z])` (`(?![^\W\d_])` is a Unicode aware equivalent) - a negative lookahead that matches a location that is not immediately followed with a letter.

Also,

- `\bt[a-z]*\b(?<!e)` matches a word boundary, `t`, any zero or more lowercase ASCII letters (any ASCII letters with `re.I`), then a word boundary marks the end of a word and the negative lookbehind `(?<!e)` fails the match if there is `e` at the end of the word
- `[^\W\d_]*` - matches zero or more more Unicode letters.

See [a Python demo](https://ideone.com/PJYq62):

```py
import re
text = r't, train => main,teene!'
cyr_text = r'таня  тане  работе'
print( re.findall(r'\bt(?:[a-z]*[a-df-z])?\b', text, re.I) )
# => ['t', 'train']
print( re.findall(r'\bt[a-z]*\b(?<!e)', text, re.I) )
# => ['t', 'train']
print( re.findall(r'\bт[^\W\d_]*\b(?<!е)', cyr_text, re.I) )
# => ['таня']
print( re.findall(r'(?<![^\W\d_])т[^\W\d_]*(?![^\W\d_])(?<!е)', cyr_text, re.I) )
# => ['таня']
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also another way of doing it:

```
re.findall(r"\b[Tt]+[a-zA-Z]*[^Ee\s]\b", my_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
[\W]([Tt]\w*[^e])[\W]
```

Any non word character followed by (capture: Tt, some optional word characters, not e) followed by first non word character